# how to fix routing issues in angular 7 and mvc?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have created an app with angular area inside mvc, but routing seems to be an issue in it,

ny rout ts file has route as  follows :

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',    
    redirectTo: '/Listing/Listings',
    pathMatch: 'full',    
  },
  {
    path: 'Listing/Listings',
    component: AppComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'Listing/Listings/details', component: TableComponent, children: [
            { path: ':id', component: ListingComponent } // url: about/item
        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'Listing/Listings/details/:id', component: ListingComponent,
    },

 ];
```

and in my mvc controller  i have details action

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        return View("index");
    }
```

but when ever i try

http://localhost:9101/Listing/Listings/details or http://localhost:9101/Listing/Listings/details/1 in both cases it loads tablecomponent.

but i am expecting like 
http://localhost:9101/Listing/Listings/details  = > should go to tablecomponent

and http://localhost:9101/Listing/Listings/details/1 => should go to listingcomponent.

why its going to tablecomponent always?
how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Add the below code to Route.config

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Angular",
                url: "*"
            );
```